# Floating point operation again

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just asked about why python gives value of 3.3 - 1.1 is 2.1999999999999997. I think because 3.3 or 1.1 represented in base 2, isn't it? At least my opinion was right http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html. But in this case 3.3 and 1.1 cannot be represented exactly as binary fractions, so the answer is approximately not exact. But, why python gives 3.3 + 1.1 = 4.4, while 3.3 - 1.1 = 2.1999999999999997, why not it gives 4.3999999999997 in instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `4.4` is in fact not exact either. You just need to print it with higher precision to see this:

```
In [2]: '%.20f' % (3.3 + 1.1)
Out[2]: '4.40000000000000035527'
```

Comment: Okay, I see it, but why 3.3 - 1.1 printed 2.1999999999999997 not 2.2 ?

Comment: I think we don't need to overcome this problem, maybe the python program works like that, at least I know that 4.4 is 4.40000000000000035527, but if you've opinion, please comment.

Comment: Because Python prints the shortest decimal string that will reproduce the binary float exactly when read back in.  `2.2 ==  2.1999999999999997` is `False`.

Comment: @Yagami: because `4.4 == 3.3+1.1` -- the float you get from `3.3+1.1` is the same float you get from `4.4`.  OTOH, you float you get from `3.3-1.1` isn't the same float you get from `2.2`--  `(3.3-1.1) - 2.2 ~ -4.44e-16`.  Python makes some efforts to show the minimum representation if that's not lossy (work by @Mark-Dickinson, IIRC.)

Comment: Yes, Python produces the shortest decimal string exactly reproducing the binary float - not "some efforts", *heroic* efforts - it's very hard to do this "reasonably fast".  Mark ported David Gay's famously complicated library for this conversion.  BTW, Mark and David are both mathematicians - don't try this on your own ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To see the exact value corresponding to a binary float, use the `decimal` module.  For example,

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(3.3 + 1.1)
Decimal('4.4000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625')
```

Note the asymmetry:  while most decimal floats cannot be exactly represented as binary floats, all binary floats *can* be represented exactly as decimal floats.  This is "basically because" 0.1 binary is exactly 0.5 decimal, but 0.1 decimal cannot be exactly expressed as a (finite) binary float.